# PHP - load/delete from DB use static methods or not?

Tags: php, database, static, load

Please, have a look at this class, I know that a piece of code outside of an app tells little about what is supposed to do, but I think you understand what is basically supposed to do and to be used for.

```
<?php

class Customer
{
   const DB_TABLE = 'customers';

   public $id = NULL;
   //all other properties here

   function __construct($associative_array = NULL)
   { 
      //fills object properties using values provided by associative array
   }

   static function load($customer_id)
   {
      $obj = new static(); //PHP 5.3 we use static just in case someone in future wants to overide this in an inherited class

      //here we would load data from DB_TABLE and fill the $obj

      return $obj;
   }

   static function delete($customer_id)
   {
      //here we just delete the row in the DB_TABLE based on $customer_id (which is the primary key of the table)
   }

   function save()
   {
      //saves $this properties into a row of DB_TABLE by either updating existing or inserting new one
   }
}
```

Besides any type of comments that you would make on the code (that are always appreciated), the main question here is: **"having read so much around on SO about how bad are `static` methods, and usage of `static` in general, in this code would you make the two methods `load/delete` not static? If yes why, could you explain with a small example."**

It seems odd to me not to make them `static` cause I think it's odd in order to create a new object loaded from DB to be forced to write every time:

```
$obj = new Customer(); //creating empty object
$obj->load(67); //loading customer with id = 67
```

instead of simply doing

```
$obj = Customer::load(67); //creates a new customer and loads data form DB
```

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on how you want you code to be structure. IMO static functions are not bad as long as you use them correctly.

For example, all my models features are similar and follow this structure:

```
class models_car {
    public static function getCar($id);
    public static function getCars();
    public static function getCarsByDriver(models_driver $driver);
    public function save();
    public function delete();
    public function isNew();
    public function getProperty1();
    public function getProperty2();
    public function getProperty3();
    public function setProperty1($value);
    public function setProperty2($value);
    public function setProperty3($value);
}
```

So in here, you can use the model as a representation of a specific entry, and if you call delete or save, it is called in the context of the object itself. If you call the getCar, getCars or getCarsByDriver, they are static because they don't pertain to a specific object, they are loaders that return a filled object.

By all means, this doesn't mean it's the best possible method but it's one i've been using for years and it has proven to create very good and manageable code.

Comment: Let's talk about the delete, that you did not declarte `static`. What if using your code I do: `$obj = getCar(78); $obj->delete();` I suppose this would delete in DB the row with `id = 78`, but what's in the `$obj` then after the deletion? For example: what happens if after the deletion I call `$obj->save();`

Comment: @MarcoDemaio I usually also have a RESET function in my objects and reset is called on LOAD/DELETE. Therefore, the object becomes a totally new instance. Like i said it's not necessarily the best way, but i like it